# How to rename Object Keys & change Object values from string to number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Alright, guys.

I am dealing with `<TimePicker/>` third party library from `React` and want to manipulate the state so I can push this new format of code into a new `object` later.

when I target a value using this library, whatever time I pick, my state turns out to be a string like this - e.g if I pick 20:30, `this.state.time` equals `"20:30"`.

I want to manipulate this `string` into an object like this:

from `"20:30"` to `time: {hour: 20, minutes: 30}` ///both hour and minutes are now numbers

My full code below:

```
import React from "react";
import TimePicker from "react-time-picker";
import './Clock.css'

class Clock extends React.Component {

    state = {
        time: '0:00',
        pushTime: [],
        value: ''
    };

    onChangeTimePickerHandler = time => {
        this.setState({time});
        let currentTime = this.state.time;
        this.props.CallbackRenderTime(currentTime)
    };

    //I am using TimePicker library for React and want to manipulate the income from the chosen time
    pushNewTimeHandler = () => {
        let time = [...this.state.time] ;// ["1", "0", ":", "0", "0"]
        time.splice(2, 1);
        let timeToOneString = time.join().replace(/,/g, "");
         let prepareStringForNewObject = (value, index) => {
             let array = value.substring(0,index) + ',' + value.substring(index);
             return array.split(',')
         };
        let newObj = {...prepareStringForNewObject(timeToOneString,2)};
        console.log(newObj); // {0: "10", 1: "00"}
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <TimePicker
                    onChange={this.onChangeTimePickerHandler}
                    value={this.state.time}/>
                    <button onClick={this.pushNewTimeHandler}>Push the Array of Time</button>
                    <p>{this.state.time}</p>
            </div>


        )
    }
}

export default Clock
```

So I have been playing around and came with this really ugly part-of-the-issue solution:

```
 //I am using TimePicker library for React and want to manipulate the income from the chosen time
    manipulateTimeHandler = () => {
        //this.state.time is "10:00"
        let time = [...this.state.time] ;// now it looks like this: ["1", "0", ":", "0", "0"]
        time.splice(2, 1);
        let timeToOneString = time.join().replace(/,/g, "");
         let prepareStringForNewObject = (value, index) => {
             let array = value.substring(0,index) + ',' + value.substring(index);
             return array.split(',')
         };
        let newObj = {...prepareStringForNewObject(timeToOneString,2)};
        console.log(newObj); //finally it became the object, but the object values are still 
                            //strings and the object keys still need to be changed into "hour" 
                           //and "minutes" {0: "10", 1: "00"}
    };
```

So on my ugly solution `pushNewTimeHandler` I still need to rename the object keys to `hour` and `minutes` and also need to transform the string values for hours and minutes into numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd split the time string by `:`, creating an array of strings, then map each string to a number, and destructure into `hour` and `minutes` on the left of the `=`. Then you can make an object of `hour` and `minutes`:

```js
const str = '20:30';
const [hour, minutes] = str.split(':').map(Number);
const obj = { hour, minutes };
console.log(obj);
```